# Whats wrong with my JSON Object

Tags: python, json

I have the following json, taken directly from http://www.jquery4u.com/json/twitter-json-example/:

```
{"results":[

     {"text":"@twitterapi  http:\/\/tinyurl.com\/ctrefg",

     "to_user_id":396524,

     "to_user":"TwitterAPI",

     "from_user":"jkoum",

     "metadata":

     {

      "result_type":"popular",

      "recent_retweets": 109

 

     },

     "id":1478555574,  

     "from_user_id":1833773,

     "iso_language_code":"nl",

     "since_id":0,

     "max_id":1480307926,

     "refresh_url":"?since_id=1480307926&amp;q=%40twitterapi",

     "results_per_page":15,

     "next_page":"?page=2&amp;max_id=1480307926&amp;q=%40twitterapi",

     "completed_in":0.031704,

     "page":1,

     "query":"%40twitterapi"}

}
```

the following error in python:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Whats wrong with my json object?

Im using the standard json package that ships with python

Comment: People are not tools: http://jslint.com

Comment: You should validate your JSON with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). It reveals you're missing a `]`. This question should be closed.

Comment: Yeah, I figured flagging for 'offtopic because its a simple typo' would be a better option..

Comment: The reason for the error is that you removed the line `... truncated ...],` but did not leave in the `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre missing a closing `]` at the bottom, this will work

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "text": "@twitterapi  http://tinyurl.com/ctrefg",
            "to_user_id": 396524,
            "to_user": "TwitterAPI",
            "from_user": "jkoum",
            "metadata": {
                "result_type": "popular",
                "recent_retweets": 109
            },
            "id": 1478555574,
            "from_user_id": 1833773,
            "iso_language_code": "nl",
            "since_id": 0,
            "max_id": 1480307926,
            "refresh_url": "?since_id=1480307926&amp;q=%40twitterapi",
            "results_per_page": 15,
            "next_page": "?page=2&amp;max_id=1480307926&amp;q=%40twitterapi",
            "completed_in": 0.031704,
            "page": 1,
            "query": "%40twitterapi"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is missing a closing ]  for the *results* parameter.

Use [this](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON objects